# unable to validate file type in php

Tags: php, file, validation, phpmailer

i am using PHPmailer for file attachment validation, below is the code for reference. as per the requirement, it should allow only PDF OR DOCX files. but i am facing issue in validating the files uploaded.

```
if(is_array($_FILES) && $_FILES['attachmentFile']['type'] == "application/pdf" && $_FILES['attachmentFile']['type'] == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" && $_FILES['attachmentFile']['size'] < 2097152)
{
$mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['attachmentFile']['tmp_name'],$_FILES['attachmentFile']['name']);
}
else
{
    echo "<p class='error'>Cannot upload other than PDF & DocX files > 2Mb.</p>";
    exit;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: `$_FILES['attachmentFile']['type'] == "application/pdf" && $_FILES['attachmentFile']['type'] == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"` it won't be exactly 2 things ever. maybe you meant `or` there?

Comment: you are right chris85, my mistake; should have put OR for file type validation AND for file size validation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your **if** condition:

```
if(is_array($_FILES) 
&& $_FILES['attachmentFile']['size'] < 2097152 
&& ($_FILES['attachmentFile']['type'] == "application/pdf" 
|| $_FILES['attachmentFile']['type'] == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document") )
{
$mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['attachmentFile']['tmp_name'],$_FILES['attachmentFile']['name']);
}
else
{
    echo "<p class='error'>Cannot upload other than PDF & DocX files > 2Mb.</p>";
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Thank you chayan for guiding. its working as expected now.